# Android studio run in debug mode still using signing config 'release'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I'm just trying to run my app in debug mode in android studio so didn't think I need a release key. From the below error, does it mean it is trying to run it in release mode?

> Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.  Keystore
>   file
>   /Users/ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/android/app/my-release-key.keystore
>   not found for signing config 'release'.

I press the button that i'm hovering over in the image.

[image]

I believe this file is the culprit:

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vepo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
                storeFile file("/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/android/app/my-release-key.keystore")
                storePassword "xxx"
                keyAlias "xxx"
                keyPassword "xxx"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.50.3") { force = true } 
    compile project(':RNMail')
    compile project(':react-native-blur')
    compile project(':react-native-interactable')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Can I edit it to also allow debug builds?

Comment: On the left side, in the vertical buttons menu there is one called `Build variants`, open the panel and select `debug` clicking on the build variant list. Then try to build again

Comment: @MatPag For some reason it only allows me to set it for the react-native-blur project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably in one of your app `build.gradle` you have something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
        storePassword 'password'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'password'
    }
}
```

The project is expecting to find the release key in the app folder but is not there. To workaround this you can temporarily comment out the `release` part above and the `signingConfig` line below in the same file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
    }
}
```

Then build your project again

Comment: Thanks, I have posted my  `build.gradle` file. Do I also add a debug field to buildTypes?

Comment: No, comment only the release parts, a default debug `buildType` is automatically added by Android Gradle Plugin

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tried your solution but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Yes i was. There was another config named beta in buildtypes removing that solved the problem thanks.